# Full screen kivy camera with buttons on top of the picture

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

[image]How can I make a full screen camera with buttons on top of the image.

```
resolution: (self.width, self.height)
```

It doesn't help, the camera still comes out with frames.  Didn't find anything about this in the official documentation.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
import time
Builder.load_string('''
<CameraClick>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Camera:
        id: camera
        resolution: (640, 480)
        play: False
    ToggleButton:
        text: 'Play'
        on_press: camera.play = not camera.play
        size_hint_y: None
        height: '48dp'
    Button:
        text: 'Capture'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: '48dp'
        on_press: root.capture()
''')


class CameraClick(BoxLayout):
    def capture(self):
        '''
        Function to capture the images and give them the names
        according to their captured time and date.
        '''
        camera = self.ids['camera']
        timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
        camera.export_to_png("IMG_{}.png".format(timestr))
        print("Captured")


class TestCamera(App):

    def build(self):
        return CameraClick()


TestCamera().run()
```

Comment: Your first problem is the order you placed your screen items.  Define the buttons first, then the camera, then the buttons will be on top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some minor changes to your code (component reorder, added `Window.maximize()` do what I think you're looking for (edit: modified to make the camera as large as possible while still
maintaining aspect ratio)

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.core.window import Window
import time

Window.maximize()

Builder.load_string(
    '''
<CameraClick>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    ToggleButton:
        text: 'Play'
        on_press: camera.play = not camera.play
        size_hint_y: None
        height: '48dp'
    Button:
        text: 'Capture'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: '48dp'
        on_press: root.capture()
    Camera:
        id: camera
        resolution: (640, 480)
        allow_stretch: True
        keep_ratio: True
        play: False
'''
)


class CameraClick(BoxLayout):
    def capture(self):
        '''
        Function to capture the images and give them the names
        according to their captured time and date.
        '''
        camera = self.ids['camera']
        timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
        camera.export_to_png("IMG_{}.png".format(timestr))
        print("Captured")


class TestCamera(App):

    def build(self):
        return CameraClick()


TestCamera().run()
```

Comment: the camera still does not take up all the space. She still has frames around the edges. Added a screen to the question.

Comment: Okay, I didn't realize you needed the camera to fill up the space.  I'll look again.

Comment: Modified to fill the space while maintaining aspect ratio.  You can change to `keep_ratio: False`  but then the display will look distorted.

Comment: I do not know how to properly say.
maybe there is something like object-fit: cover; from css? so that when using keep_ratio: False, the image is not distorted but cropped

Comment: If we knew what the window available was, maybe we can change the camera `resolution` value to the same aspect ratio?  Just a thought.  But crop does seem to make the most sense.

Comment: The screen resolution may vary. Depends on the phone. Ideally, I would like to achieve a result, such as a camera in the telegram application